# How to show notification after some time?

Tags: android

I need to show notification on tap of button but not at that time but after some time like somedays.I have written code for that,but no output is showing.

Please check and tell where I am wrong and what should I add to make it work.

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageButton Button1;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int date;
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        Button1.setTag("ON");
        //Button1.setSelected(selected);
        Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v.getTag().toString().equals("ON")) {
                    v.setTag("OFF");
                     v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_off);
                    // NotificationHandler notification = new NotificationHandler(MainActivity.this);

                    //notification.sendNotification("New Notification Received");
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    //Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "A New Message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
                }else {
                    v.setTag("ON");
                     v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_on);
                }


            }
        });
    }



    public void startAlarm() {
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(2013, 11,13, 8,  30,  1);
        long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();         // notification time
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderService.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, when, pendingIntent);
            }



    public class ReminderService extends IntentService {
        private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;

        public ReminderService(){
            super("ReminderService");
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "static-access" })
        @Override
          protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time

            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "reminder", when);
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.flags |= notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent , 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "It's about time", "You should open the app now", contentIntent);
            nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);
        }

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my notificationhandler class:

```
public class NotificationHandler {


    Context context = null;
    public int contentinfo = 1;


    public NotificationHandler(Context context){

        this.context = context;
    }

    //Send Notification start

    public void sendNotification(String message) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

        alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


            contentinfo++;
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("New Message")
            .setContentText("messgae")
            .setContentInfo(""+contentinfo)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle());
            // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);


            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                            0,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                            );
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
            int mId = 1;
            notificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());



        //Send Notification end


    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How far in the future are those events? Is your application still running at this point or most likely not? I would also like to know, why do you want to achieve this? It sounds like annoying ads, to open your application again.

Comment: It can be after somedays..My application is running now.

Comment: Sorry but it is my requirement..

Comment: Consider using `Calendar.add()` instead of `Calendar.set()`. This is most likely your issue. Hardcoding dates is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**I didn't go through complete notification code. First of all you are not calling startAlarm() function in the code.**

Call setAlarm() from onClick().